# Appending NSMutableStrings - Exepected "." before "." token error

Tags: nsmutablearray, append, nsmutablestring, inheritance

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm thinking its because the NSMutableArray's *name and *field are declared in a different file.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface xmlToUrl : NSObject {    

    NSString *base_url;
    NSMutableArray *field;
    NSMutableArray *name;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *base_url;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *field;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *name;

@end
```

and

```
#import "xmlToUrl.h"

@implementation xmlToUrl
@synthesize base_url;
@synthesize field;
@synthesize name;

-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        field = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [base_url release];
    [field release];
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The NSMutableArrays are filled in the ViewController class:

```
//nodeContent is just a NSMutableString being added to the *name and *field NSMutableArrays

if([ending isEqualToString:@"name"]){
        if(![nodeContent isEqualToString:@""])
        {[xmlToUrlObject.name addObject:nodeContent];}
    }
    else if([ending isEqualToString:@"field"]){
        if(![nodeContent isEqualToString:@""])
        {[xmlToUrlObject.field addObject:nodeContent];}
```

Error = Expected '.' before '.' token. (on the first line of the code below)

What I want for output: *url string contains base_url, urlPart2, and urlPart3 all joined in order.

ex:

base_url = @"www."

urlPart2 = @"mywebsite"

urlPart3 = @".com"

url = @"www.mywebsite.com"

```
//xmlToUrl is an instance of its own class (.m file)  It contains the *name and *field NSMutableArray
//xmlToUrl.h is inherited in this file

NSMutableString *urlPart2 = [xmlToUrl.name objectAtIndex: 0];
    [xmlToUrl.name removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableString *url = [xmlToUrl.base_url stringByAppendingString:urlPart2];

    if([xmlToUrl.field count] != 0)
    {NSMutableString *urlPart3 = [xmlToUrl.field objectAtIndex: 0];
    [xmlToUrl.field removeObjectAtIndex:0}
    url = [url stringByAppendingString:urlPart3];

     [urlPart2 release];
     [urlPart3 release];
```

Comment: What kind of object are xmlToUrl and xmlToUrl.name?

Comment: I'll edit it.  xmlToUrl is a class (instance of it).  name is a NSMutableArray

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going on but try `[[xmlToUrl name] objectAtIndex: 0]`  Can you please illustrate how xmlToUrl is instantiated, I have a suspicion that it's something to do with that.

Comment: I'm adding more to the post to try to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a property on a class, and not on the instance:

```
@interface xmlToUrl : NSObject {
```

and

```
NSMutableString *urlPart2 = [xmlToUrl.name objectAtIndex: 0];
```

You can only access the property on an instance of xmlToUrl, just like you do in the following line of code:

```
{[xmlToUrlObject.name addObject:nodeContent];}
```

Here, xmlToUrlObject is an instance, and not the class.